# update field that could be null in stored procedure

Tags: jquery, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table that contains two columns which could be null.

I want to build a stored procedure to edit that table. in the stored procedure I did this:

```
@ID INT,
    @newBuildingName NVARCHAR(250),
    @newLocation NVARCHAR(3000),
    @newImage VARBINARY(MAX) = NULL,
    @newNote NVARCHAR(3000) = NULL,
    @result BIT OUTPUT
```

Not I can't decide in this point if the user has entered values for `newImage` or `newNote` fields, so I can't say

```
UPDATE myTable SET image = @newImage, note = @newNote
```

because these two fields might already have values and in this way I would be deleting those vaules,

what should I do?

**What I thing is**
make an `if-else` statement and try if the first field is null so make my update without it and then if my second field is null then make my update statement without it and if neither of them is null then make a full update statement but I thing that this is a very teduis process.

Is there any other solution plesae ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the coalesce function:

```
UPDATE myTable 
SET 
    image = COALESCE(@newImage,image),
    note = COALESCE(@newNote,note)
```

If image is not null then it won't be changed. Same goes for the note column

Comment: but in this case if it is already not null, there won't be any update, what is the solution pease?

Comment: Swapping the values, i.e. `image = Coalesce( @newImage, image )`, will update the field if the new value is not NULL. The explicit way would be to add a bit for each vague field and use something like `image = case when @SetImage = 1 then @newImage else image end`.

Comment: Coalesce parameters swapped as HABO suggested

Answer (score 1):

Make the if-else statements in such a way you can decide on the entities you want to update without actually committing the update.

You must already have the value of the entire entity in your code, say in your model. Please check for the following scenario.

```
if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(@newImage))
{
     //include the values @newImage to the entity to update
}
if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(@newNote))
{
     //include the values @newNoteto the entity to update
}
EntityToUpdate.saveChangestoDB();
```

Comment: please are you sure? this is a very essential part in my database

Comment: what is entityToUpdate ?

Comment: It is a good practice to keep an entity of data together whenever you are fetching data from DB, or while writing back to DB. Its just conceptual, in your case

Comment: Please follow @Gruff Bunny's answer. It's elegant and neat.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UPDATE myTable 
SET image = CASE WHEN image IS NULL THEN @newImage ELSE image END
,note = CASE WHEN note IS NULL THEN @newNote ELSE note END
```

of course you may want to use the ISNULL function also...for example

`note = CASE WHEN ISNULL(note,'') = '' THEN @newNote ELSE note END`

to cope with both note IS NULL and note equal to '' (empty string)